# Doubly LinkedList doesn't show the exact value I'm searching for

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

**I'm searching for an exact value of a node in my Doubly LinkedList using the searchByName method.**
It doesn't show the data that I want even If I pass a value that is present in the LinkedList.

```
public void searchByName(String param) throws Exception{
    Node currentNode = start;
    String theFirstName = currentNode.firstName.toLowerCase();
    String theLastName = currentNode.lastName.toLowerCase();
    param = param.toLowerCase();
    if (start == null) {
        throw new Exception("List Underflow");
    }else{
        String id= "Student ID", ln="Last Name", fn="First Name", course="Course", section="Section", yl="Year Level";
        System.out.format("%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-5s\t%-10s\t%s", id, ln, fn, course, section, yl);
        System.out.println();
        while(currentNode.next != null){
            if (param == theFirstName || param == theLastName) {
                System.out.format("%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-5s\t%-15s\t%d", currentNode.studentID, currentNode.lastName, currentNode.firstName, currentNode.course, currentNode.section, currentNode.yearLevel);
                System.out.println();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not found");
                break;

            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        if (currentNode.next == null){
            System.out.format("%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-5s\t%-15s\t%d", currentNode.studentID, currentNode.lastName, currentNode.firstName, currentNode.course, currentNode.section, currentNode.yearLevel);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

My main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
 StudentRecord senators = new StudentRecord();
 senators.insertEnd("110007", "Lacson", "Ping", "BSCS", "BSCS-III-A", "Active",  3);
    senators.insertEnd("110008", "Angara", "Sonny", "BSCS", "BSCS-III-B", "InActive",  3);
  senators.searchByName("Lacson");
}
```

Link to gist: https://gist.github.com/30b27d3612f95fc2ced99f50c4f23c14

Comment: Compare Strings (and any other non-primitive objects) with equals(), not ==.

Comment: I tried doing that. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Then that would be a second bug. But the code as posted is wrong. Compare Strings with equals(), not with ==.  Your second bug is that you stop looking and print "not found" as soon as you find an entry that does not match,

Comment: Yes, I just tried using equals() and it still didn't work.

Comment: When you've fixed one bug, and it still doesn't work, that means there's at least one more bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many bugs in your method 2 major ones:

1. Strings should be compared with equals method not ==
2. Your algorithm to traverse the list is wrong
3. Always use your own exception (LinkedListOutOfBoundsException)
4. Do not modify input parameters inside the function
5. Unnecessary else statement since it throws.
6. The last if is absolutely useless.
7. Try to use a logger

```
    public void searchByName(String param) throws LinkedListOutOfBoundsException {
        if (null == start) {
            throw new LinkedListOutOfBoundsException("List Underflow");
        }
        if (null == param) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("param must not be null");
        }

        Node currentNode = start;    
        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (param.equalsIgnoreCase(currentNode.firstName) 
                    || param.equalsIgnoreCase(currentNode.lastName)) {
                break;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        if (null == currentNode) {
            LOGGER.info("Not found");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Found {}", param);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a good comprehensive answer. The only part I'd quibble with is the 'logger' advice; there's no reason to add that in a simple beginner's exercise.

Comment: Well, that and the 'null == x' clauses. Not the way we speak is that.  Needlessly indirect is inverting the order. Clear should code be.

Comment: While I agree with you I developed this habit since for example when you have to test a string with a string constant let's say the constant is called: NULLY, the way you would do that is: NULLY.equals(startString), similarly null == start ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating theFirstName and theLastName when changing nodes.

Also, compare strings with equals, not ==.